# Splitting into teams algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a hard algorithmic problem for y'all.

So I am a coordinator of a 5-week basketball program for 20 young kids. Each week, I want to form 4 teams of 5 kids each. These kids will play on the same team for every day of the week. This will give them a good opportunity to get to know everyone on their team.

However, every new week, I would like to create new teams. I would like an algorithm that would create the 5 sets of 4 teams (one for every week). There is only one condition. Each kid must have been on the same team with any other kid at least once. If this is not possible, please explain why. Thanks!

-- Update --

So I don't think this is possible because of the following reason:
Let's say the kid's names are {'a', 'b', ..., 't'}
For kid 'a' to interact with every other kid, his teams for each week could look like as follows:
week 1: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
week 2: {'a', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
...
week 5: {'a', 'r', 's', 't', 'b'}

Look at week 5, 'a' has to be put on the same team as 'b' (or another kid 'a' has already played with). As a result, 'a' only has room for one repeat in the entire 5 weeks. For this algorithm to work, there must only be 20 repeats total (one for each kid). But every week other than the first week requires 8 repeats at least per week.

As a result, if you can devise an algorithm that maximizes the number of kids that each kid gets to be on the same team with, that would be great! I'll post my final algorithm regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the hard algorithmic problem. What did you try ?

Comment: I tried a brute force attempt. It didn't work out. I don't think this is possible so I'm working on a way to maximize the number of kids each kid gets to be on a team with.

Comment: This type of problem is studied in the part of mathematics known as design theory. Originally it was used to design experiments. I suggest asking on math.stackexchange.com (general mathematical question), or if you don't get responses there in a few days, then MathOverflow.net (research mathematics). Few programmers would be familiar with the tools developed in design theory for this type of problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy your argument -- if there were 5 teams of 5 kids each, there exists a 6-week schedule where each kid has each other kid as a teammate exactly once.

Comment: My argument serves to prove that it is impossible for a 5-week schedule, not a 6 week schedule. I'm sure that there is a solution for the 6 week schedule, I'm currently researching the social golfer problem and it is very interesting.

Comment: Aztrorisk, I don't understand your argument. What is your justification for the the following statement? "Every week other than the first week requires 8 repeats at least per week."

Comment: @Douglas For example, if the teams were divided into for week 1:

    {a,b,c,d,e}
    {f,g,h,i,j}
    {k,l,m,n,o}
    {p,q,r,s,t}

Notice that in order to construct a team for week 2, you would need 5 people. By taking 1 person from each team in week 1, you will only have 4 people since there are only 4 teams. You must take another person from the same team to create a 5 person team. As a result, two people would have used up their repeat in this one team. Multiply this by the 4 teams will give you 8 repeats.

Comment: Nice argument, but it's worse than that. For every week, and a team on another week, there must be at least one ordered pair of kids on the team that was on the same team the other week. For 6 weeks, each kid has 24 teammates out of 19, so there must be 5 repetitions, or a total of only 100. However, there must be at least 6 choose 2 times 8 repetitions, or 120 repetitions over 6 weeks. So, there is no working schedule for 6 weeks, either.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is very closely related to the (Fully) Social Golfer Problem in the literature. Since each kid has 4 teammate slots/week * 5 weeks = 20 teammate slots, this instance is very tight, and constraint solvers are the way to go.

Comment: Great answer. In OP's case, a Brute Force would actually work, as 20 choose 5 is only ~16k.

Comment: @AndyG: What does 20 choose 5 give you? One team in one week? To me, a brute force would start with a particular division of teams on the first week, and then one of the (20 multichoose 5,5,5,5)/4! divisions on each of the next four weeks, so there are about 20!^4/(5!^16 4!^4) ~ 10^35 possibilities.

Comment: @DouglasZare: I meant that you could brute-force generate all possible, unique divisions of teams and that number would be 20 choose 5. At that point, I was thinking you could greedily build player one's 4 week schedule first such that overlap amongst teammates was minimal, and then incrementally build player two's 4 week schedule, constrained by player one's, and so on. So, not completely a brute-force solution, sorry.